# render :action with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, render, parameters

I have one Class with 2 methods.
The first method is called by the view with some GET parameters ( params[:page] ).
I would like to save those params and send them by a render action to my second method.

```
class exemple
  def first
    ## sql save of params[:page] 
    render :action => "second"
  end

  def second
    ##
    ## Here I need my params[:page] to do paginate stuff
    ##
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

So my question is : **How can I send params with a  render :action ?**

thanks :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
render :action => "second"
```

When you render, then your method written in `:action` is not called, only the view with that action name is called.

In your example, when you render, then your method `second` is not called but you are instead rendering the `second.html.erb` view.

For more details refer to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464).

To call that method you have to use [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000468), which looks something like the following:

```
redirect_to :action => "second", :page=> 4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! :)
I tried with redirect_to and it's working but I would like to send ALL the GET params of the first method to the second.
Do you know a solution or I have to send all the params one by one ?