# rendering action with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have this problem. I have the edit view that updates a product and here my action in product_controller

```
  def edit_product

    @product = Product.find(params[:product][:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { render action: "edit_product"  }
      else

        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

The problem is that when i call for edit view i pass the id_product while now i can't in the render action and it gives error

How to solve it and render something like edit?id_product=  ??

this is my products resources

```
  resources :products, :only => [:index] do
    collection do
      post 'new_product'
      post 'edit_product'
    end    
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150641/render-action-with-params

Comment: no, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What error? If you pass "id_product" then you should access it with "params[:id_product]".

Comment: in this way i can't get errors from validation

Comment: please post the part of your `config/routes.rb` related to the products ressource!